Angular19 app showing blank page only on Iphone devices
Hello and thanks for reading
I have an angular19 website which works fine on PC and android devices. On some of Iphone devices, however, it shows nothing and a blank page.
any feedback?

Your iPhone version likely isn't supported by angular.
Check the browser support.
The alternative for you is the generate an .browserslistrc config and add the supported version.
You can do that with ng generate config browserslist
